# Is "Eq.1 derives into Eq.2." equivalent to "Eq.2 is derived from Eq.1."?

Tags: verbs

I'd like to ask about the usage of the verb "derive".

On an academic paper of math, do you write "*Equation 1 derives into the following equation.*" in order to express "*The following equation is derived from Equation 1.*"?

I usually use the latter expression. However, my friend wrote the former. So, I got confused about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a mathematician I would always say the same as you

> Equation 2 is / can be derived from Equation 1

or some similar wording to suite the context. I've never seen it used another way.

Although I would understand what is meant, your friend and the paper quoted in gotube's answer is just wrong. I think I would have written it *...Eq.(1) can be rearranged to give ...* or *From Eq.(1) we get ...*. If you must use derive then *... The following can be derived from Eq.(1)...*

Answer (score 1):

I found [an example](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/RAAD_2012/cgdqKEN08ssC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22derives%20into%22&pg=PA268&printsec=frontcover) of it:

> ... only a part of it is compensated and Eq. (1) derives into ... (2).

[image]

This is from a publication called, "RAAD 2012
21th International Workshop on Robotics in Alpe-Adria-Danube Region, 10-13 September 2012 : Naples, Italy : Proceedings"

This single example is evidence only that it *is used*, not that it's correct or natural to use it in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of "derives from" is "implies", not "derives into".

"Derives from" literally means "[is down river from](https://www.etymonline.com/word/derive)".  The passive connotations of being downriver are consistent with "from", but contradictory to the "pushing" connotations of "into".

The following sentence is natural (in a mathematical context):

> Equation 1 implies the following equation: